# Prevent library from publishing if peerDependencies are missing

Tags: angular-library, peer-dependencies, nx-angular

I've created [this NX workspace](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo) with some libraries which are published to NPM and github.

[The following state of the repository](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo/tree/d27d1576835b1e0a83bc732b136be1ca31677f9b) causes the following error on installation

```
npm i @mintplayer/ng-json-ld
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~16.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from @mintplayer/ng-json-ld@16.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mintplayer/ng-json-ld
npm ERR!     @mintplayer/ng-json-ld@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (@angular/platform-browser)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"16.2.1" from @angular/router@16.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/router
npm ERR!   peer @angular/router@"16.2.1" from @mintplayer/ng-json-ld@16.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@mintplayer/ng-json-ld
npm ERR!     @mintplayer/ng-json-ld@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-26T17_45_08_268Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-26T17_45_08_268Z-debug-0.log
```

package.json

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
  "rxjs": "^7.8.0"
},
```

[This](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo/blob/d27d1576835b1e0a83bc732b136be1ca31677f9b/libs/mintplayer-ng-json-ld/src/lib/directives/json-ld/json-ld.directive.spec.ts#L4) turns out to be the culprit.

I added the [`@angular/router`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-seo/commit/d4caf92bd12cb850c169dc07815c4c31228bb026) as a peerDependency, and now I can install the package without problems

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^16.0.0", // <-- explicitly added this
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
  "rxjs": "^7.8.0"
}
```

`@angular/router` isn't used anywhere in the code. However somewhere in a specfile I need to use it. And if I don't range the version in the packagefile (`^ x.x.x`) I get the above error, even though I don't use the package in code, only in unit-tests.

These problems have been biting me several times. Is there a way I can prevent these imports in my libraries if the corresponding `package.json` doesn't yet contain the dependency?

Similar discussions:

- [imports in .spec files can trigger a circular dependency error on build](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/10290)

I'm getting the impression I have to use a feature called **enforce-module-boundaries**, but I don't know yet how.